# Getting CID, LAC and signal strength of all cell towers in range

Tags: java, android, gsm, signal-strength, cellid

Currently I am trilaterating my Android with the cells in my network. It is even more accurate than I thought it would be. But not as accurate as I want it to be. So I want to involve more towers than I get from getNeighboringCellInfo. I want to get the Cell ID and signal strength of every tower in range. Of every network operater. Is there a way to "ping" the towers, so they answer with cellID, Lac and signalstrength? Somehow this has to be possible. 
And can I scan the 2G and 3G (and 4G) parallel? Or can I switch between them programmatically? 
Any suggestions? Hope I'm clear enough...

Answer (score 2):

Seems `TelephonyManager` and `getNeighboringCellInfo()` are what you are looking for.

Here's a example, which is easy and straight forward:

```
/* first you wanna get a telephony manager by asking the system service */
TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

/* then you can query for all the neighborhood cells */
List<NeighboringCellInfo> neighbors = tm.getNeighboringCellInfo();

/* here's something you can get from NeighboringCellInfo */
for (NeighboringCellInfo n : neighbors) {
    Log.v("CellInfo", "" + n.getCid());
    Log.v("CellInfo", "" + n.getLac());
    Log.v("CellInfo", "" + n.getPsc());
    Log.v("CellInfo", "" + n.getRssi());
}
```

Make sure you include all the permissions required, such as `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` or `READ_PHONE_STATE`, depending on what API you'll be using, in your manifest file, or it'll simply crash.

Oh btw this only works for 2G. 3G or above doesn't support this kind of operation.

Comment: "So I want to involve more towers than I get from getNeighboringCellInfo." I am already reading CIDs from the neighboring cells. But I want to get ALL CIDs of EVERY network operator in range.

Comment: tm.getAllCellInfo() is better choice .

Answer (score 2):

As of now, this is the proper way of getting neighbouring cell information:

```
    TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    List<CellInfo> cellInfoList = telephonyManager.getAllCellInfo();
    for (int i = 0; i < cellInfoList.size(); i++) {
        if (cellInfoList.get(i) instanceof CellInfoWcdma) {
            CellInfoWcdma cellInfoWcdma = (CellInfoWcdma) cellInfoList.get(i);
            /* Get LAC, strength etc. here */
        } else if (cellInfoList.get(i) instanceof CellInfoGsm) {
            CellInfoGsm cellInfoGsm = (CellInfoGsm) cellInfoList.get(i);
            /* Get LAC, strength etc. here */
        } else if (cellInfoList.get(i) instanceof CellInfoLte) {
            CellInfoLte cellInfoLte = (CellInfoLte) cellInfoList.get(i);
            /* Get TAC, strength etc. here */
        } else if (cellInfoList.get(i) instanceof CellInfoCdma) {
            CellInfoCdma cellInfoCdma = (CellInfoCdma) cellInfoList.get(i);
            /* Get strength etc. here */
        }
    }
```

Now,

1. You can find LAC as `cellInfoWcdma.getCellIdentity().getLac()`, similarly for `cellInfoGsm` and `cellInfoLte`. Note that CDMA does not contain LAC. Also note that LTE has TAC instead of LAC which are similar except their terminology.
2. You can find strength as `cellInfoWcdma.getCellSignalStrength().getLevel()`. Similar is for LTE, GSM and CDMA. Note that you can `getLevel`, `getDbm` or `getAsuLevel`, whatever you are interested in.
3. For CID, you can get it as `cellInfoWcdma.getCellIdentity().getCid()`, similarly for LTE and GSM. Note that LTE has `getCi` instead of `getCid`. Also note that it is not available for CDMA.
4. If you're interested in MCC and MNC, you can get it as `cellInfoWcdma.getCellIdentity().getMccString()` for API Level >= 28, else use `cellInfoWcdma.getCellIdentity().getMcc()`. Note, you cannot get MCC and MNC for CDMA.

You can make your own model class and store what all values you need by making their objects (where I have commented). Store those objects in a list. Don't forget to add permissions to Manifest.

Comment: Very interesting answer, helped me a lot :)