# Get Neighboring Cell Information From ServiceMode Samsung

Tags: android

I tried getting neighboring cell signal strengths like this: [Getting CID, LAC and signal strength of all cell towers in range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12491256/getting-cid-lac-and-signal-strength-of-all-cell-towers-in-range) -- however this doesn't seem to be supported with most Samsung phones (just returns blank list). I get a similar result when I run the "GSM Signal Monitoring" app -- no nearby cell info available.

This being said, I CAN access this information if I manually dial *#0011#; ServiceMode pops up, and if I choose "back" and "Neighbour Cell" I can get a number of neighboring cell masts and their signal strengths.

My question is as follows: Is there a way to programatically get this data from ServiceMode, or another way to get this data other than the way mentioned in the url that will work on Samsung phones? The data is clearly there; the question is how to get it.